# Samsung Galaxy i8262 stuck on boot screen after flashing

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, rom-flashing, custom-roms

I flashed my *Samsung Galaxy i8262* ROM with odin and accidentally I selected a ROM file from phone not from PDA, so when it finished and I restarted my phone and it stays on Samsung Logo

[image: Odin windows]

Can one help me please :'(

Comment: try to flash it with PDA .Nothing will happen.put your phone in download mode and connect it with USB after you select the file using PDA.

Comment: yes, i do it but nothing happend, it stay also on samsung logo!

Comment: wait for some time like 10 mins if nothing will happen
then check your firmware version of your country or in which country you purchased the phone and flash that firmware you can download the official firmwares at www.sammobile.com and register for free and download

Comment: Bro. Remove ur battery wait for few minutes then switch on ur phone. Automatically boot ur phone factory settings.